# Why does CollectionMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault returns a ref nullable TValue?

Tags: c#, dictionary, ref

The other available helper that is:

```cs
ref TValue GetValueRefOrNullRef<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key) where TKey : notnull
```

Can return a null ref (`Unsafe.NullRef<TValue>()`) but the value itself is what it is (since TValue is not constrained).

But:

```cs
ref TValue? GetValueRefOrAddDefault<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, out bool exists) where TKey : notnull
```

Returns a `TValue?`. (And the reference itself cannot be null.)

There SHOULD be something I'm missing here and if anyone can explain, it'll be great!

Answer (score 1):

I realized that this is required to accomodate reference types. Since the helper adds the `default(TValue)`, the result may obviously be a null, regardless of the TValue parameter nullability.
And this applies also to nullable value types!

(My mind was focused on value types).

This leads to a funny couple of signature where the `OrDefault` equivalent is not nullable (because it's a `OrNullRef`) and the `OrAdd` is nullable...